# Debugging a Timer Job

Tags: feature, timer-jobs, debugging

I was not able to do something a little more elaborate with my timer job so I decided to check if something basic works. So I tried the code below - but it keeps giving me this error - why?

### **UPDATE**

Error text is: ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace AlertAudit
{
public class AlertMailer : SPJobDefinition    {
    
    public AlertMailer()
        : base() {
    }

    public AlertMailer(string alertName, SPWebApplication webApplication)
        : base(alertName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
    {
        this.Title = "Alert Mailerv1";
    }

    public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
    {
        base.Execute(contentDbId);
        // get a reference to the current site collection's content database
        SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];
        
        using (SPWeb web = new SPSite("http://myRootSite/").OpenWeb())
        {
            foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

thanks,

KS

Comment: is it possible to post the error message directly as text? for some reason the image is not displaying (unsure - it could be blocked at my end). Ta.

Comment: Console.WriteLine ?? You are writing timer job not a console application!?

Comment: you have mentioned that "it keeps giving me this error".. I can't see it (the error image), so if you could type the error message above within your question itself.

Comment: thanks for (Update) posting "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - how can you write to console, if you are running timer job and not a console application?

Second - does your `list.Title` contain anything that looks like `{0}`? `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` at `Console.WriteLine` would mean, that you didn't give enough parameters to format string. This method works exactly like `string.Format()`:

```
Console.WriteLine("foo {0}, bar {1)", foo, bar);
```

If you don't give enough parameters, you get this kind of exception.